# Can an interaction of two particles produce only one real particle?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws

Typical Feynman diagrams show more than one outgoing particle. For example:

[image]

Usually this is a consequence of various conservation laws. For instance, a free electron and positron pair cannot annihilate producing a single photon without violating either energy or momentum conservation.

Is it possible for only one real particle to be produced in an interaction of two particles? For example, can an up-type quark "combine" with a down-type anti-quark of the same color to produce a real W boson? Or any other example. Has a single-particle outcome actually been observed?

Comment: Consider any particle decay and time reverse it.

Comment: @knzhou, Can you give an example of a single real particle decaying in two particles?

Comment: @knzhou Yes, this is an obvious theoretical thought, but my question is about specific observed examples. In addition, some decays, such as the free neutron decay, produce more than two particles like $1\rightarrow 3$ , so reversing them looks more like $2\rightarrow 2$ after flipping the third particle to the other side as an anti-particle.

Comment: @Arthur Okay, we got kaon to two pions. Excited hydrogen atom to hydrogen atom and photon. Higgs to two photons. Higgs to two Z bosons. Do those work for you?

Comment: It is a little tricky making a one to two decay because of all the conserved quantum numbers but they definitely happen!

Comment: @knzhou "Quark to two gluons"? Wouldn't this violate the quark number conservation?

Comment: Sorry, I typed too fast, you’re right.

Comment: @knzhou The photon absorption by an atom is an obvious candidate, but it doesn't work here, because the photon actually is absorbed by an electron moving to a higher energy state in its interaction with the nucleus. As such, this is more than two particles interacting.

Comment: Z boson to anything is a good example: $Z\rightarrow x\bar{x}$, where $x$ is most any SM fermion. Particularly electron/positron, since I'm sure we've seen it both ways in that case.